# How to canonize URLs with words that contains apostrophes or accents and reverse

Tags: php

I'm using this method, converting my marketplace website urls like

```
myexample.com/toys/boston    // 1 word: Boston
myexample.com/toys/new-york  // 2 words: New York
myexample.com/toys/ofallon   // 2 words: O'Fallon
myexample.com/toys/ahualoa   // 1 words: Āhualoa can be any accent
```

and i want to be able to convert it back to the page title,
but so far i just get "Toys in Ofallon" or "Toys in Ahualoa"

what's the best practice to convert to safe urls
and be able to revert back to the original correct name

> eg. "Toys in Āhualoa" or "Toys in O'Fallon"

Comment: How you convert the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reverse throwing away information. If you represent è, é, ê, ë and e as `e`, then you have no way of knowing what the original data was.

You therefore have to store the information somewhere. A database table will do the job.

```
slug VARCHAR(255),
title VARCHAR(255)
```

… for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` which will convert all characters to % references and back.

So for example, if your city is O'Fallon it will convert to:

`myexample.com/toys/O%27Fallon`

This is a safe URL, however, it's not the prettiest - it won't convert to lowercase characters for example. UTF8 is supported in URLs, so things like Āhualoa can be left as they are.

For decoding in your PHP application, if you run `O%27Fallon` through `urldecode()` it will revert to `O'Fallon`.

There are perhaps some other tricks you can use to get the formatting how you'd like it. For example, running `strtolower()` to convert the city to lowercase characters, and then `ucwords()` to bring it back. And perhaps combining it `str_replace()` for replacing spaces with dashes and vice versa.